# How do I receive responce after I POST data to an url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, post

I have this code;

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude=%lf&longitude=%lf&provider=network&accuracy=%lf&hiz=%lf&retrieveTime=%@",
                  locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,
                  locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude,
                  locationManager.location.horizontalAccuracy,
                  locationManager.location.speed,
                  dateString];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *sUrl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"serviceUrl"];
NSString *swoclString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/saveLocation.php", sUrl];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:swoclString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(conn) {
    NSLog(@"Location Save Successfully");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Location Save Error");
}
```

I can receive the data in the server side. And on the iOS side I can see the log "Location Save Successfully".

How can I receive the response from the server without [implementing other methods](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2011/04/10/Writing-your-first-http-request-in-objective-c/)?

Comment: `without implementing other methods` ..... thats how you do it, the tutorial you linked too quite clearly explains it. There are many networking libraries that use different syntax / structure if this is causing you an issue for some reason

Comment: You are missing all the part of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, but it's deprecated (old tutorial), you should use `NSURLSession` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection to post your data to the Server. Below is an example how you can post JSON.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<YOUR-URL-STRING>"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

 NSError *error;
 NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:<YOUR_JSON_DATA> options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *tmp = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *resp = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSLog(@"%li",(long)resp.statusCode);
        if(resp.statusCode==200){
            NSMutableArray *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
    }];`
```

The block is used to return the response by the server. For example the HTTP-Status Code and the response data. If you use json you can convert the Data with the NSJSONSerialization class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest ios coding standards you must have to use URLSession object to send any request to the API calls because `DEPRECATED: The NSURLConnection class should no longer be used.  NSURLSession is the replacement for NSURLConnection`. But still, if you want to continue with an old procedure, there are three ways to send API request.

**P1:**

```
-(void)procedure1{
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = nil; /** replace with your request object **/
    NSURLResponse *serverResponse = nil;
    NSError *connectError = nil;

    /* thread bloker request */
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestObject returningResponse:&serverResponse error:&connectError];
    if (connectError == nil) {
        //parse server response data (i.e, json or xml)
    }else{
        /* handle connection error */
    }
}
```

**P2:**

```
-(void)procedure2{
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = nil; /** replace with your request object **/
    /* thread free request */
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestObject queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {
        if (connectionError == nil) {
            //parse server response data (i.e, json or xml)
        }else{
            /* handle connection error */
        }
    }];
}
```

**P3:**
the last one is a bit different than the other two,

```
@interface TestViewController ()<NSURLConnectionDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData* responseData;
@end



-(void)procedure3{
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = nil; /** replace with your request object **/
    NSURLConnection *connectionObject = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:requestObject delegate:self];
    [connectionObject start];
}
```

here in this procedure you are required to invoke `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    connection = nil;
}
```